# ODBC ISAM_EOF without any reason

Tags: c#, database, odbc, cobol

I have a strange behavior with an ODBC Driver and the underlying COBOL database. The database driver is acuODBC of AcuCorp(now Microfocus), the database itself is a COBOL database.

The DSN is a system DSN and works just fine. Via Access/Excel u can read/write data with the DSN successfully.

In C# the `ODBCConnection.ConnectionState` is open. Retreiving the table headers works just fine. But when reading data, a strange error occurs. Here is a summerize of the trace log:

- [Retreiving Column Headers]
- ISAMRestrict - NO_ISAM_ERR
- ISAMRewind - NO_ISAM_ERR
- ISAMNextRecord – **ISAM_EOF**

This occurs when I add a `WHERE` clausel to the `SELECT` statement. When I do not add a `WHERE` clausel and just retreive the whole table, it takes incredible long (about 12 minutes for 40000 records), but at least I retreive data.

So my question would now be, has anyone else occured such a strange behavior with an ODBC driver? End of File where data should be?

Just as a side note, I have contacted Microfocus too, if they have a solution I will post it here.

Comment: What is a COBOL database???

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL @ piet.t, It is a file based database use way in the past like 10 years ago.

Comment: I know about COBOL, it's the database-part that makes me wonder...

Comment: Honestly, I do not know that much about the database itself, since I only deal with the ODBC driver. I thought it would be a COBOL database.

Comment: It is perhaps a proprietary AcuCOBOL thing, from the error messages using ISAM under the covers. You've probably already taken your best shot, by contacting Micro Focus. Do you have any other code that is working with this? Have you tried something really simple (beyond what you have mentioned). 12 minutes for 40000 records does sound like a problem. You may get lucky here, but don't count on it.

Comment: The underlying `database` is Acu's VISION proprietary indexed file format. The EOF suggests that whatever your query was, it isn't finding any matching records. Can you post the code of the query (specifically the WHERE clause) you are using. Note, accessing a vision indexed file will be slow unless you are using a specific index in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be Windows UAC reliant. As our application run in compatibility mode, UAC visualization is active and causing may some problems. The reason for this is, that the COBOL databse is a file based database, and the client where are coding for uses these files in ODBC DSN config directly instead of running an ODBC server to handle the requests.

So the UAC leads to some strange behavior.

Comment: Micro Focus have a similar product which might help you called AcuXDBC. It implements a fully SQL-compliant relational database engine on top of the Vision indexed files and allows you to access them like a 'proper' database. It's ODBC and JDBC compliant.